# Maven / SVN: cannot release:prepare -> commit failed when not passing -Dusername and -Dpassword

Tags: maven, svn

I don't know what's wrong here. When I execute release:prepare I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
[ERROR] svn: E215004: Commit failed (details follow):
[ERROR] svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://localhost/svn/repo/myrepo/myapp/trunk/com.mydomain.mygame-TRUNK'
[ERROR] svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
[ERROR] Authentication failed
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The user and password, defined in settings.xml will be recognized by Maven, checked by....

```
$ mvn help:effective-settings
```

I can even connect to the repository by svn command. User and password is also correct.

When I execute with this command, release:prepare goes through:

```
$ mvn release:prepare -Dusername=myself -Dpassword=mypass
```

**settings.xml**

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>svnrepo</id>
      <username>myself</username>
      <password>mypass</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://localhost/svn/repo/myrepo</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://localhost/svn/repo/myrepo/myapp/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:svn:https://localhost/svn/repo/myrepo</url>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>svnrepo</id>
        <url>svn:https://localhost/svn/repo/myrepo/myapp/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>svnrepo</id>
        <url>svn:https://localhost/svn/repo/myrepo/myapp/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Why does it not work when I omit username and password?

Answer (score -1):

I see that you are using https. Probably it has to do with your server's certificate. Is it using a self-signed certificate?
If so, setup maven to trust these: [like this](http://trumaze.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/how-to-ignore-self-signed-ssl.html)

Summary:
Create a file called svn-settings.xml in your user directory (e.g: C:\Users\YourUsername.scm\svn-settings.xml) with the following content:

```
<svn-settings>
  <trustServerCert>true</trustServerCert>
</svn-settings>
```

Comment: Problem comes from authentication not certificate itself and as you can see in blog link you posted error message is completely different.